# Push item in array and see if item already exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

**Hello guys! I have created the following code and want to know how to fix the code so when I add the same student the if statement can run properly. Thx a lot for your help**

```
class Student {
constructor(name, email, community) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.community = community;
}
```

}

```
class Bootcamp {
constructor(name, level, students = []) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.students = students;
}

registerStudent(studentToRegister) {        
    if (this.students.forEach(s => s.email === s.email)) {
        console.log(`The student ${studentToRegister.email} is already registered!`);
    } else {
        this.students.push(studentToRegister);
        console.log(`Registering ${studentToRegister.email} to the bootcamp ${this.name}.`);
    } 
    return this.students;
}
```

}

```
// For testing

// Creating new Bootcamp
const webDevFund = new Bootcamp("Web Dev Fundamental", "Biginner");
const fullStack = new Bootcamp("Full Stack Web Dev", "Advance");

// Adding new Bootcamp
const Max = new Student("Max", "max@fyard.net", "PAP");
const Bird = new Student("Bird", "bird@fyard.net", "Cap-Haitien");
const Yayad = new Student("Yayad", "yayad@fyard.net", "Cayes");
const Meg = new Student("Meg", "meg@fyard.net", "Miami");

// Verification
webDevFund.registerStudent(Bird);
webDevFund.registerStudent(Max);
fullStack.registerStudent(Yayad);
fullStack.registerStudent(Meg);
fullStack.registerStudent(Yayad);
```

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything. You can't use it as a condition in an `if` statement (it will always be undefined, which evaluates to false). Look at [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Also, your test (`s.email === s.email`) is always true. If you use Array.some, you'll have to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
    if (this.students.forEach(s => s.email === s.email)) {
```

You want:

```
    if (this.students.find(s => s.email === studentToRegister.email)) {
```

See the difference between [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Find RETURNS a matching value, forEach returns nothing (thus is falsy).

Also note that if you are not going to have multiple instances of the same student details, you can compare the student objects directly without looking at email address.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Array.some` instead:

```js
if (this.students.some(s => studentToRegister.email === s.email)) {
    console.log(`The student ${studentToRegister.email} is already registered!`);
}
```

Also, consider using `Map` or `Set` in this case:

```js
const map = new Map;

if (!map.has(student.Email)) {
    map.set(student.Email, student);
}
```

```js
const set = new Set;

if (!set.has(student)) {
    set.add(student);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help my friend. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how the program is crashing.  If you could provide error details that'd greatly help, but on cursory glance, this could be a bug:

`if (this.students.forEach(s => s.email === s.email)) {`.

`s.email === s.email` will always evaluate to true.